# Need Pointers | Using JDBCTemplate | CQ 5.5

Tags: oracle11g, osgi, jdbctemplate, aem, osgi-bundle

I need some pointers/suggestions on following scenario.

**Scenario:**

We are trying to use `JDBCTemplate` in `CQ 5.5` for querying database (`Oracle 11g`). As first step we have `integrated CQ with Spring Framework`. Now for JDBCTemplate to work it `requires JDBC driver` that needs to be loaded separately into CQ as it is not available with Spring jars. The jar that is required is available here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html  and jar in my case is “`ojdbc6.jar`” that contains `OracleDriver` class (**JavaDoc**: *http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html*) required to register the driver to create connection with Database.

**Problems/Suggestions required on following points:**

1. As oracle 11g is commercial product so there is no repository available online for it (for pom dependencies), we need to create a separate local repository for it. (**Need pointers; is there any other way to do it?**)
2. Jar mentioned above is not OSGi. **So how to approach in that case?** (I have created OSGi bundle by following directions mentioned here *http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/21893960212/how-to-turn-a-jdbc-driver-jar-into-an-osgi-bundle-jar*)
3. In this process of converting this jar to OSGi Bundle I have to remove versions mentioned with Imported Packages in MANIFEST.MF file. (As I understand that CQ by-default picks the latest version that is available for any class, there may be problem when a new version of any class is available that is not compatible with current version. **Need pointers; should this be looked into priority? Has anybody faced any issue due to this in any project**)

**Current Status:**

By converting ojdbc5.jar to OSGi bundle; I was able to use JDBCTemplate. **But looking for some pointers to check is there any other approach someone has followed in other project to achieve scenario mentioned above?**

Answer (score 0):

1. The oracle driver is not published to any public maven repo. So indeed you will have to put the jar into your own maven repo
2. In Apache Karaf there is a nice feature where you write wrap: in front of a bundle url and it automatically creates a bundle on the fly using the bnd tool.
   If CQ does not have such a feature then you will have to create the bundle on your own. In this case the maven bundle plugin can help you. You can depend on the oracle jar using a maven dependency. Then you can define exports for the packages of the oracle jar. Bnd should then automatically inline the classes in you bundle jar. Another option is the maven shade plugin. You can take a look at the source of the servicemix bundles. There you find poms to bundle a lot of plain jars.
3. Not sure what exactly you mean. As far as I know the oracle driver does not have any external dependencies.

I have written a [DB tutorial for Apache Karaf](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access) that explains how to deal with the oracle driver and how to create data sources without depending on the concrete driver.

The solutions in the tutorial can not be used 1:1 in CQ but it will surely give you some pointers.